# How to build WPF Modern UI as plugin DLL for Revit

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, revit, modern-ui

For a couple of Windows Applications I've used FirstFloor.ModernUI successfully. When I want to implement this framework as a plugin for Autodesk Revit 2019 API, I get the following error:

[NullReferenceException](https://hastebin.com/raw/uyuhuxemiv)

This is the MainWindow.xaml :

```
<mui:ModernWindow x:Class="WpfApp5.MainWindow"
              xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
              xmlns:mui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI"
              Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" 
              ContentSource="Home.xaml"> 

 <mui:ModernWindow.MenuLinkGroups>
     <mui:LinkGroup DisplayName="home">
         <mui:LinkGroup.Links>
             <mui:Link Source="Home.xaml" />
         </mui:LinkGroup.Links>
     </mui:LinkGroup>
     <mui:LinkGroup DisplayName="settings">
         <mui:LinkGroup.Links>
             <mui:Link Source="Settings.xaml" />
         </mui:LinkGroup.Links>
     </mui:LinkGroup>
 </mui:ModernWindow.MenuLinkGroups> 

</mui:ModernWindow>
```

This is the plugin Main :

```
using System.Windows;
using Autodesk.Revit.DB;
using Autodesk.Revit.UI;

namespace WpfApp5
{
    [Autodesk.Revit.Attributes.Transaction(Autodesk.Revit.Attributes.TransactionMode.Manual)]
    public class Main : IExternalCommand
    {
        public Result Execute(ExternalCommandData commandData, ref string message, ElementSet elements)
        {
            var MainWin = new MainWindow();

            ResourceDictionary DictionaryModernUI = new ResourceDictionary();
            DictionaryModernUI.Source = new System.Uri(@"/WpfApp5;component/Assets/ModernUI.xaml", System.UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            MainWin.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(DictionaryModernUI);

            ResourceDictionary DictionaryModernUILight = new ResourceDictionary();
            DictionaryModernUILight.Source = new System.Uri(@"/WpfApp5;component/Assets/ModernUI.Light.xaml", System.UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            MainWin.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(DictionaryModernUILight);

            MainWin.Show();

            return Result.Succeeded;
        }
    }
}
```

[Link for Visual Studio Solution](https://share.stand.com.tr/public/8b47c3)

Same code sample works a windows executable. If I omit *ContentSource="Home.xaml"* main window renders but without any content. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I created a sample project for AU a few years back that used WPF.  You'll need to modify  RvtWindow to inherit from ModernWindow instead of Window, and there may be more changes required.  Project is here: https://github.com/StarkBIM/SampleRevitAddin

Comment: In my case MainWindow inherits from ModernWindow and I can get the empty main window rendered in modernui style. I've checked your solution and we have a same approach however I believe ModernUI have some intrinsic issue preventing to load a content page. Thanks

Comment: The difference between my project and your sample is that I'm using a custom window type specified in the XAML (<core:RvtWindow />) rather than directly using <mui:ModernWindow />.  You probably need to create the custom window type using code (inheriting from ModernWindow), and then use that window type in XAML.  I don't think that using the code-behind for the XAML window is sufficient.